# Editor doesn't load properly on my self-hosted WordPress 3.3

Tags: editor

I have a self hosted WordPress install on my small VPS running WordPress 3.3.1 powered by nginx. As of the last 3.3 update, the editor fails to load properly - I cannot see the toolbar etc.

When trying to load and edit any existing posts, even the text of the post doesn't load.

My browser's error console shows the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input            load-scripts.php:153
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: fullscreen is not defined       editor_plugin.js:1

[Screenshot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LiqT.png)

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: try disabling plugins as this problem is mostly caused by corrupted plugins

Comment: @phantom.omaga disabling didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from [wordpress.org/forums](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-28-jquery-error):

> WordPress 2.8 includes a concatenation of scripts and CSS. This puts
> the quality of these scripts at a higher level than before.
>
> The temporary solution is to place it in the wp-config.php one of
> these two values
>
> define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );
>
> or
>
> define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', true);

Now this is from over a year ago, worth a shot.

Comment: Thank you, `define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );` seems to have worked for now. Not sure why it cropped up only after 3.3 update. Do you know how I can get to the root of the issue?

Comment: I have the same problem but the solution  `define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );` doesn't help. I'm using `wp_editor` function to add an editor for my settings page.

Answer (score 0):

when you uploaded the wordpress files are you sure all the files were successfully uploaded because filezilla and other ftp programs some times miss some files and they are listed in failed transfer open your ftp program check if there are any such files and if you are not sure or removed those files or they are not there re upload all the files overwriting all of the previous ones or go to http://www.yoursite.com/wp-admin/update-core.php and reinstall from there.

Comment: also try switching your theme and see if it works